# How do I find out an effective apache config setting in a directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache-config

Suppose you want to find out about a specific apache config   setting/directive, say `LimitRequestBody` in a certain directory `path/to/somewhere`.

You don't know and don't where the actual file responsible for the setting in effect is - it might be the main apache config, or any .htaccess on the way down (`path/.htaccess`, `path/to/.htaccess` or `path/to/somewhere/.htaccess`).

Is there a convenient way to find out, which actual setting is in effect in `path/to/somewhere` (optionally which file the setting originated from)?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can without some kind of 3rd party tool (of which I am not aware of any). It's an age-old problem of multiple per directory .htaccess files. It is better to have just a single .htaccess file in the root. Or, ideally, disable .htaccess altogether and just use the server config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stick to not using .htaccess, you can get a decent amount of information from using mod_info. If you use .htaccess files, there is currently no module that will tell you "what/who caused this", simply because it's very very difficult to figure out due to how rules are put in place internally.

I am, as a hobby project, working on having mod_lua (which is a core part of the 2.4 distribution) be able to tell you this in the near future, but right now, the simple answer is: You can't.